# Form for user to input data and submit to run sql command

Tags: sql-server, infopath

We're looking for an quick and easy way for an HR person to enter data into a couple fields and then have them click submit and have it execute some SQL Update query on the database. We don't need to return anything to the user (maybe just a submission successful notification, if that).

We don't really want to create a webpage for this since we lack the PHP/C# knowledge to do this quickly and easily. Can Sharepoint somehow be used for this? I've heard InfoPath is also an option.

Running SQL Server 2008 and Sharepoint 2007.

Comment: pardon my language but you might try just using Microsoft Access. SharePoint can do it but would still require you to create the webpage within SharePoint and a data source to the database.

Comment: Can I read an Access DB from within SQL Server? I'd need to report from it with other tables.

Comment: I believe you could add it as a linked server within SQL Server. Access can be used just as a front end form to the actual database in SQL Server. Access would not be used to store the data, just a front end to it in place of the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use SharePoint and InfoPath to achieve this, if you have at least SP2007 Standard Edition..

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/submit-form-data-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-HP010107060.aspx) is a tutorial how to submit form data to a SQL server and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/In+the+Office/Creating-Browser-Enabled-Forms-With-InfoPath-2007) is a video tutorial how to make your form "browser enabled".